# RxJava2 passing data through flatMap on a Single

Tags: java, rx-java2

In rxjava 1 there Observable had this flatmap method

[public final  Observable flatMap(Func1 collectionSelector, Func2 resultSelector)](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#flatMap(rx.functions.Func1,%20rx.functions.Func2))

That allowed you to pass/combine the initial result to the flatmap subscriber.

How can I achieve the same result with RxJava2?

I have a Single that emits `A`, I need to get `B` based on `A` and then use both `A` and `B` to perform an action.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have the same method on RxJava2, both on [Observable](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#flatMap(io.reactivex.functions.Function,%20io.reactivex.functions.BiFunction)) and [Flowable](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Flowable.html#flatMap(io.reactivex.functions.Function,%20io.reactivex.functions.BiFunction)) ,
but, in both RxJava1 and 2, there is no such operator for `Single`, you can transform [`Single` to `Observable`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Single.html#toObservable()) and then apply this operators.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried CombineLatest (http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/combinelatest.html)

Basically you can emit A and B and then return another object based on the function result:

**RXJava1**

```
Observable
  .combineLatest([Add here your A observable],
                 [Add here your B observable],
                 new Func2<A, B, Result>() {
                    @Override
                    public Result call(A a, B b) {
                        //Do your stuff here combining both results and return the result expected
                    }
                 })
```

**RXJava2**

```
Observable
  .combineLatest([Add here your A observable],
                 [Add here your B observable],
                 new BiFunction<A, B, Result>() {
                    @Override
                    public Result apply(A a, B b) throws Exception {
                        //Do your stuff here combining both results and return the result expected
                    }
                 })
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer by [Yosriz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3903847/yosriz) is correct but to add a code example:

Assuming the following:

```
class A {}

class B {}

class AB {
    private final A a;
    private final B b;

    AB(A a, B b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }
}

interface AbRepository {

    Single<A> getA();

    Single<B> getB(A a);
}
```

Note that the method `getB` requires an `A` as a parameter.

Then you can do:

```
abRepository.getA()
        .toObservable()
        .flatMap(new Function<A, ObservableSource<B>>() {
            @Override
            public ObservableSource<B> apply(A a) throws Exception {
                return abRepository.getB(a)
                        .toObservable();
            }
        }, new BiFunction<A, B, AB>() {
            @Override
            public AB apply(A a, B b) throws Exception {
                return new AB(a, b);
            }
        })
        .firstOrError();
```